# How to implement a Logout function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I implemented a Login page using MYSQL JWT, and localstorage in Reactjs that works perfectly,
but now I want to implement a Logout functionality and I have no idea how to do this.
I have attached my Login component and my Settings component where I put my Logout functionality.
Can someone help me or give me hints?

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: "",
            password: "",
            
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    login = () => {

        const { email, password} = this.state;

        axios("/users/login", {
            method: "POST",
            data:{
                email, 
                password,
            }
        }).then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            this.props.history.push("/track");
            
            console.log(response.data)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            
            
<div>

<div className="header text-white">
           <h1 className="text-center fw-bold">GREEN</h1>
           <p className="lead fw-bold">OPTIMISE YOUR BEHAVIOUR TO MINIMISE CO2 EMISSIONS</p>
          
       </div>
          
           
            <div className="input" >
                <input 
                className="mb-3" 
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={this.state.email}
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /><br></br>

                <input 
                className="mb-3" 
                type="password" 
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={this.handleChange} /><br></br>

                <button className="login-button ml-3" onClick={this.login  }>Sign in</button>
                <p className="text-white mt-2">Not a member? <Link to="/register" className="text-black">Register</Link></p>
            </div>
             </div>
           
        )
    }
}
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import './Settings.css';
import { AiOutlineLogout } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { SiGnuprivacyguard } from 'react-icons/si';
import { GrUserSettings } from 'react-icons/gr';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";



export default class Settings extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: ""
        }
    }

    logOut = () => {
      
        
      };

      render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavBar />
            <Header />
            <div className="settings fw-bold">
         <Link className="settings-nav" > <GrUserSettings /> Account Settings</Link><br></br>
         <Link className="settings-nav">  <SiGnuprivacyguard/> Terms and Privacy</Link><br></br>
         
         <div className="settings-nav" onClick={() => this.logOut()}>  <AiOutlineLogout /> Logout </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the token from localStorage?

Comment: Thank you, I just tried to remove the email and token from locaIStorage and It's working :) : logOut = () => {
            localStorage.removeItem("email");
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            this.setState({ email: "" });
            this.props.history.push("/login");
          };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logout = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios("/users/logout", { method: "POST"});

    // remove token from local storage and redirect to login page 
    localStorage.setItem('token', null);
    this.props.history.push("/login");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

1. Logout using your an endpoint to kill the session in your backend
2. Remove the token from your local storage
3. Redirect to the login page.